# Webview missing from list of contexts

Tags: javascript, ios, appium, device

I am running tests using WebdriverIO with Appium. Recently my tests started failing when trying to switch to webview context (`driver.switchContext('WEBVIEW_1')`). Tests are running on a real iPhone. I am running tests on a new test device.

Comment: Can you please specify the ios and appium versions?

Comment: Appium 1.14.0 
iOS 12.4

Comment: I have created this question only because it wasn't obvious, one should enable web inspector on an iPhone device before running tests. Appium and iOS versions don't really matter here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the device navigate to Settings > Safari > Advanced and enable Web Inspector.